# Sorting the keys of a dictionary based on different values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ranking

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {"A":{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, "B":{"a":5, "b":6, "c":7}, "C":{"a":4, "b":6, "c":7}}
```

I want to sort the keys "A", "B" and "C" in a list, first on the basis of numerical values of "a", then if some tie occurs on the basis of numerical values of "b" and so on.

How can I do it?

Comment: Edit your question and add the ultimate sorted list.

Comment: re ad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value?rq=1 and try to work it out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sorted(d, key=lambda key:(d[key]['a'], d[key]['b'], d[key]['c']))
```

And here is a general solution in case you have an arbitrary number of elements in the inner dictionaries:

```
sorted(d, key=lambda key:[value for value in sorted(d[key].items())])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = {"A":{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, "B":{"a":5, "b":6, "c":7}, "C":{"a":4, "b":6, "c":7}}
>>> 
>>> d.items()
[('A', {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}), ('C', {'a': 4, 'c': 7, 'b': 6}), ('B', {'a': 5, 'c': 7, 'b': 6})]
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: [y[1] for y in sorted(x[1].items())])
[('A', {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}), ('C', {'a': 4, 'c': 7, 'b': 6}), ('B', {'a': 5, 'c': 7, 'b': 6})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of your dictionary like so:

```
my_list = [(key, value) for item in d.items()]
```

Then sort the list using whatever criteria you have in mind:

```
def sort_function(a, b):
   # whatever complicated sort function you like
   return True if a > b else False

my_list.sort(sort_function)
```